# Threads are not alive using python multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using the multithreading module of python but the code doesn't work sometimes. I print the count of active threads and found that sometimes the started threads are not active. Here is the code:

```
def do_stuff(q,obj):
    while not q.empty():
        item=q.get()
        print item
        q.task_done()

for i in range(num_thread):
    worker=threading.Thread(target=do_stuff,args=(q,Files,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()
    print worker.is_alive()
print threading.active_count()
print threading.enumerate()
```

I got False for the is_alive() function and there's only one thread (the main thread) in the active thread list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your threads did not have time to start yet.

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.isAlive)

> `is_alive()` `isAlive()`
>
> Return whether the thread is alive.
>
> This method returns `True` **just before the `run()` method starts** until just after the `run()` method terminates. The module function
>   `enumerate()` returns a list of all alive threads.